# Jump script using AddForce not working

Tags: unity, vector, rigidbody, jumping

I am making a simple jump script by adding a separate script to the character.

[I got the character from the Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/jammo-character-mix-and-jam-158456#content) and I have left it untouched. I have searched the solution and similar problems to this, and I changed the force or JumpHeight to a pretty high value. But it is still nothing. The logs are printed out just fine.

```
public class JumpScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Rigidbody rb;
public float JumpHeight = 7.0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        Debug.Log ("PRESSSED");
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (Vector3.up * JumpHeight);
        Debug.Log (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is that JumpScript attached to and what do you want to use the rb for?

Comment: To the character of course.@Zibelas

Comment: 1) Your mass of your rigidbody could be too high. 2) You could try to add the force as an impulse .AddForce (Vector3.up * JumpHeight, ForceMode.Impulse);

Comment: Already tried those things but still no luck.

Comment: Well, the asset you have linked has no rigidbody, they handle all movement with the MovementInput script. If you comment out the Update method from that script, you will notice that the jump script is working.

Comment: I have already added a rigidbody myself and I am a beginner so I have no idea which is blocking this or how can I make this right so that character will still maintain everything and jump.

Comment: This is not a well-made jump script. I would recommend that you throw this code away, and do not use other code from the same source. It makes easily avoidable mistakes, like repeatedly searching for a component instead of caching it, using a continuous force instead of an impulse or velocity change for an instantaneous action like jumping, and hard-coding key codes instead of using remappable inputs. There are thousands of better examples of jump scripts available with a quick search. Try another one until you find an example that works for you.

Comment: @DMGregory I'll try that, sir! Tho I have tried a lot ahhaha

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure your character has a Rigidbody attached, and no Character Controller (if you're intending to move this character with physics)
2. Ensure the character's Rigidbody is set to dynamic, and its constraints allow movement on the y axis
3. Disallow rotation on the Rigidbody, to keep your character from tipping over accidentally
4. Verify that the character's collider is not interpenetrating with any scenery that might trap them in place
5. Use velocity changes or impulses to set velocity, not forces

---

Here's a simple jump script that helps fix a couple of these:

```
// This tells the editor to enforce "only use this script on objects with Rigidbodies".
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Jump : MonoBehaviour {

    public float jumpHeight 
    
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    float _jumpVelocity;        
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    Rigidbody _body;
    
    // When you tune the jump height in the inspector, automatically
    // calculate the physics values that will get you to that height.
    void OnValidate() {
        // Cache a reference to our body so we don't have to search at runtime.
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    
        // Solve v(t) = v(0) + a * t for v(t) = 0.
        float secondsToJumpApex = Mathf.Sqrt(-2f * jumpHeight / Physics.gravity.y);

        // Substitute into h(t) = h(0) + v(0) * t + (a/2) * t^2 and solve for v(0).
        _jumpVelocity = Physics.gravity.y * secondsToJumpApex; 
    }

    void Update() {
        // Use a named input set up in the Input Manager, not a hard-coded key.
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            // Jumps are instantaneous, so use VelocityChange instead of a gradual push.
            _body.AddForce(jumpVelocity * Vector3.up, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```